# jquery datatable, button render but become disabled

Tags: jquery, css, datatable

I have a datatable :

http://s7.postimg.org/po8prohob/enable_Disable.png

when I click a "DISABLE" button it change to "ENABLE" and vice virsa, but when you click in the same changed button, it does not have any action like the first time clicked.

```
// Attach delete
$('#saiMdataEnvListTable .delete').on('click', function() {  
    var ans = confirm("Do you want to delete this Environment?");
    if(ans==true){
        var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
         var target_row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0); // this line did the trick
            var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(target_row); 

              oTable.fnUpdate('T',aPos,1);
              oTable.fnUpdate('<td class="center"><a href="JavaScript:void()" class="button enable" style="margin:10px;margin-right:30px;">Enable</a></td> ',aPos,6);


        $.ajax({
            url: "deleteEnv.do",
            data: "env=" + nRow.id + "&flag=" + "T",
            success: function(response) {
                  oTable.fnDraw(false)
               toastr.success(response.message);  
            }
        })            
    }
}); 

// Attach enable
$('#saiMdataEnvListTable .enable').on('click', function() {  
    var ans = confirm("Do you want to enable this Environment?");
    if(ans==true){
        var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
          var target_row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0); 
           var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(target_row); 
            oTable.fnUpdate('F',aPos,1);
            oTable.fnUpdate('<td class="center"><a href="JavaScript:void()" class="button delete" style="margin:10px;margin-right:30px;">Disable</a></td> ',aPos,6);

        $.ajax({
            url: "enableEnv.do",
            data: "env=" + nRow.id + "&flagt=" + "F",
            success: function(response) {
                 oTable.fnDraw(false)
               toastr.success(response.message);  
            }
        })    
    }
});
```

Thanks, your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're creating the delete button element inside the enable click event, so it might not be getting it's event binding. Change your event handlers to look like this, using `on` or `delegate`, but starting at the document level

```
$(document).delegate('#saiMdataEnvListTable .delete', 'click', function (event) {
  // ...
})
```

Comment: Thank you elzi, I spent the whole day fighting with this, it's working now, to be honest I don't know what is the difference between :  // $('#saiMdataEnvListTable .delete').on('click', function() {    AND
   $(document).delegate('#saiMdataEnvListTable .delete', 'click', function (event) {